# Trying to improve this query

Tags: sql, database, select, query-optimization

I'm trying to improve the performance on this query. What are some things that I can do to optimize it?

```
SELECT * FROM bldng 
WHERE bldng_type LIKE '%PTR%' OR bldng_type LIKE '%FACILITY-A%' 
OR bldng_type LIKE '%FACILITY-B%' AND area_sqf > 500
```

Comment: if you don't need every column you can replace your `*` with a list of  columns you do need.

Comment: There's very little you can do that's not data-dependent. Your query depends on examining the entire contents of every single value in `bldng.bldng_type`; if `bldng` is big, then that will be slow. Instead, you should look at improving your table design so that this sort of query is not needed.

Comment: How long is the complete list of strings that can go in `bldng_type` column?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the wildcard prefix, you're going to do a full scan of `bldng`.  If you can remove the wildcard prefix, and add an index on `bldng_type`, your performance should increase greatly.  having `%text%` is slow

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using '%search string%' two percent signs on the ends breaks the index on those columns. It will be better to use a fulltext index instead. If you want real performance and accuracy you can use Lucene or Sphinx Full Text search engine.

Comment: Just what I was going to say. I will also point out that many people use this structure when they don't need to and if you don't really need the first characters to be a wildcard, eliminate it. SQL Server also has it's own full text search if the OP is using that.

Comment: Ok, so would a CASE statement help any as well? I was thinking about that...but not sure if it'll be more efficient

Comment: I don't think you can call lucene or sphinx function from within a database. But that is an interesting concept.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to select out different categories of buildings.  I would suggest putting a 'bldng_category' column on the bldng table.  This way you can use simple queries like this:

SELECT * FROM bldng 
WHERE bldng_category in ('PTR', 'FACILITY_B', 'FACILITY-B') AND area_sqf > 500

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you could use [Table Hints (MSDN link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). NOLOCK is common.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing `area_sqf` and specifying only the columns you need rather than using `*` may help.